# Ruby on Rails Select As doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, subquery

I am trying to get a "Select As" query statement to work, but keep getting an error and am not sure why it is not working.  Per the API docs, the format is correct.

```
User.select("firstname as fname")
```

Results in:

```
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT firstname as fname FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil>, #<User id: nil>]
```

However if i use:

```
User.select(:firstname)
```

I get:

```
  User Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "users"."firstname" FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil, firstname: "John">, #<User id: nil, firstname: "Brian">,
```

So I can see from the query why it's not returning the results, but I don't understand why its creating the incorrect query.  (The actual query I need to use the select as on is more complicated then this query, but I was trying to use the simpler query to try to figure out why it wasn't working properly.

The reason I need to use a select as query is because I have two separate objects from two very different tables that i need to join together and change one of the column names so I can sort by that column.  I'm not sure if there is an easier way to change the name prior to combining the objects.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change `firstname` field to `fname`?

Comment: Yes, only temp for this query with a sql select as statement. Not permenantly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `alias_attribute :firstname, :fname` in the model and then use `User.select(:fname)` in the controller as well.

Comment: Thanks Uday.  Should this work in the console as well?  I am trying to test it out by using it in the console, but get a "no such column" error.

Comment: directly use `alias_attribute` in your app

Comment: So the syntax was switched, it should be alias_attribute :fname, :firstname.  I got it to work in the console, but I still have the same problem, when the record is returned, the key is still the original column name, not the alias name:                                                                  2.1.1 :001 > User.select(:fname).where(id:1)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users"."firstname" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: nil, firstname: "John">]>

Comment: I'm not sure if that comes out clearly, but the returned recrodset uses the firstname key even though the select statement used the alias.  I need it to use the alias when returning the recordset, which I would normal do with a SQL Select firstname as fname statement, but for some reason that does not work correctly either

Comment: use `find_by_sql` for direct sql query, for more details visit http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid hard coding the SQL statement.  Looks like I may not have another option.  Still not sure why the SQL Select as statement doesn't work.  Can't seem to find any documentation on it either.